# Restore settings to default settings

Tags: c#, wpf, config, configuration-files, ini

**Situation**

I'm creating a  project in WPF where I want to store some data in config files. Like menu Items, tree items and some other data. The ways I could implement this was by using:

1. XML Files
2. [Ini Files](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI)
3. [Integrated Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx)
4. Databases

**What is the problem**

I chose the ini file approach with this [library](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser).

But if a user removes a config file I should have a default back up of my settings, so my program can run without any problem. The options to restore to the default settings that came up to me where:

1. Getting the default settings from the server
2. Creating a class that stores the default settings, when a file gets removed this class can restore it.

   - I think this is a dirty solution because these classes are mostly unused but are included in the project. And if I follow the SOLID and DRY approach I will end up whit +- 7 more (unused) classes.
   - By doing this I will also ruin the idea of getting the settings
     out of my code.
3. Using the integrated settings from visual studio that has this already build in

   - I don't think this is meant for storing large amounts of data, like
     tree items, menu items.

**Question**

How should I restore my data to default (by recreating the config file whit the default settings) when a user removes the config file? What approach should I take, or are there any that I missed?

Comment: Your question is too broad because you don't specify any criteria for the decision of a particular implementation.

Comment: use  filewatcher event for delete

Comment: @dymanoid I've updated my question I hope that it makes more sense now

Comment: Configuration is an object in the project, upon startup this object can have default values (bonus: you have settings even before loading configuration). Then you load configuration (deserialize as another object) and if that fails - you just keep original object with default values untouched (otherwise its instance will be replaced by loaded one). That approach works pretty well with `XmlSerializer` and json, due to their easy object serialization, not sure about other options capabilites, e.g. in case of database you will need a copy (local?) of database with default values.

Comment: Can't you include the default fallback settings in a file that you compile into the assembly as a resource? Then the user won't be able to remove this one.

Comment: @mm8 That is a good one, I did't think of that one it would work very well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the default fallback settings in a file that you compile into the assembly as a resource.

The user won't be able to remove this one like they can remove a file in the output directory of the executable.